# Visual Studio Code can't find my main class

Tags: java, visual-studio-2019, classpath

Everything was working fine yesterday.   I've re-run some old stuff I wrote for class that worked fine, thinking maybe I made an error in my new assignment and just couldn't find it with the same results.

It looks like the classpath is wrong, however, I've also reset it in cmd and compiled and run my code successfully there.  It just isn't working in Visual Studio.

I checked `java.home` in settings and it is the correct path for my jdk (jdk-12.0.2)

I also uninstalled and reinstalled VSC with the same result.

This is the message I get.

```
PS C:\Users\wvert> & 'C:\Users\wvert\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.22.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-12.0.2/\bin\java' '--enable-preview' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\wvert\AppData\Local\Temp\vscodesws_ab536\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'Sales'
Error: Could not find or load main class Sales
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sales
```

Comment: Your error is caused by the Java compiler being unable to find a required class (Sales).  Since that class is a custom class, your issue is caused by a project configuration error, in that you have not provided the correct path to that class.

Comment: I'm not clear on where that setting is in Visual Studio, I thought it was in the same place as the java.home.   What's odd is it worked perfectly fine two days ago, so I don't know what changed.